# How to combine duplicate rails objects and update all references

Tags: ruby-on-rails, duplicates

I'm working on a Rails app (Ruby 1.9.2 / Rails 3.0.3) that keeps track of people and their memberships to different teams over time.  I'm having trouble coming up with a scalable way to combine duplicate Person objects.  By 'combine' I mean to delete all but one of the duplicate Person objects and update all references to point to the remaining copy of that Person.  Here's some code:

**Models:**

Person.rb

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rostered_people, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :rosters, :through => :rostered_people
  has_many :crews, :through => :rosters

    def crew(year = Time.now.year)
      all_rosters = RosteredPerson.find_all_by_person_id(id).collect {|t| t.roster_id}
      r = Roster.find_by_id_and_year(all_rosters, year)
      r and r.crew
    end
end
```

Crew.rb

```
class Crew < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rosters
  has_many :people, :through => :rosters
end
```

Roster.rb

```
class Roster < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rostered_people, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :people, :through => :rostered_people
  belongs_to :crew
end
```

RosteredPerson.rb

```
class RosteredPerson < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :roster
  belongs_to :person
end
```

`Person` objects can be created with just a first and last name, but they have one truly unique field called `iqcs_num` (think of it like a social security number) which can be optionally stored on either the `create` or `update` actions.

So within the `create` and `update` actions, I would like to implement a check for duplicate Person objects, delete the duplicates, then update all of the `crew` and `roster` references to point to the remaining `Person`.

Would it be safe to use `.update_all` on each model?  That seems kind of brute force, especially since I will probably add more models in the future that depend on Person and I don't want to have to remember to maintain the find_duplicate function.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'scalable' way to deal with this is to make the de-duplication process part of the app's normal function - whenever you save a record, make sure it's not a duplicate. You can do this by adding a [callback](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html) to the Person model. Perhaps something like this:

```
before_save :check_for_duplicate

def check_for_duplicate
  if iqcs_num
    dup = Person.find_by_iqcs_num(self.iqcs_num)
    if dup && dup.id != self.id
      # move associated objects to existing record
      dup.crews = dup.crews + self.crews

      # update existing record
      dup.update_attributes(:name => self.name, :other_field => self.other_field)

      # delete this record
      self.destroy

      # return false, so that no other callbacks get triggered
      return false
    end
  end
end
```

You'll want to make sure that you index the table you store Person objects in on the iqcs_num column, so that this lookup stays efficient as the number of records grows - it's going to be performed every time you update a Person record, after all.

I don't know that you can get out of keeping the callback up-to-date - it's entirely likely that different sorts of associated objects will have to be moved differently. On the other hand, it only exists in one place, and it's the same place you'd be adding the associations anyway - in the model.

Finally, to make sure your code is working, you'll probably want to add a validation on the Person model that prevents duplicates from existing. Something like:

```
validates :iqcs_num, :uniqueness => true, :allow_nil => true
```

Comment: Aha! This does indeed sound like the way to go - I'm just concerned that updating the `dup.crews = dup.crews + self.crew` statement will become a classic 'gotcha' of maintaining this site as more associations are linked to the `Person` model.  But I suppose that's something I'll need to document...  thanks for the help!

Comment: ... I'll probably be combining this with some more research on the [`reflect_on_all_associations`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods/reflect_on_all_associations) method...